# filter method returns empty array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have the following doubt, I have this const

```
export const STATUS = [{
  0: 'Rascunho',
  1: 'Enviado',
  2: 'Processando',
  9: 'Processado',
  3: 'Agendado',
  4: 'Protocolizado',
  5: 'Suspenso',
  6: 'Erro protocolo',
  7: 'Erro processamento',
  8: 'Erro leitura',
}];
```

and I'm trying to access the values ​​using the following method

```
  public constantFormatter(params) {
    const status = STATUS.filter((p) => p === params.value);
  }
```

however it is always returning empty and I am not able to understand why, has anyone had the same problem?

Comment: Your array has a single item and it's an object, so unless params.value is that exact object the predicate will always be false

Comment: What is params.value? How is this function called?

Comment: That is an array containing one element, an object literal. Looks like you just want the literal so remove the square brackets.

Comment: I'm not familiar with TypeScript, however, couldn't you just make your object into an array? Then call each item using it's index (e.g. `STATUS[3]` - returns Processado).

Comment: I have edited my answer several time, please recheck, I think this version would be more what you wanted.

Comment: also... you included the tag typescript. Are you sure you're using typescript ? it doesn't look like you're using it to me. At least in the code provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you most likely want is an enum:

```
export enum STATUS {
  Rascunho,
  Enviado,
  Processando,
  Processado = 9, // Only these two are needed since enums auto-increment and this one was out of order
  Agendado = 3,
  Protocolizado,
  Suspenso,
  "Erro protocolo",
  "Erro processamento",
  "Erro leitura",
};

export function constantFormatter(params: {
  value: number
}): string {
  return STATUS[params.value];
}
```

Comment: this is really what I wanted to do, the enum fell perfectly for me, thanks for the explanation and the time spent

Comment: No problem, also with an enum you can go both ways (e.g. STATUS["Suspenso"] === 5)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a property that doesn't exist ('params').

You have an array with one object only. And this object doesn't have a params property. params is the variable with the index value. In order to access an object with a variable value, you can't use object.whatever. You have to use object[whatever].

Here:

```js
const STATUS = [{
  0: 'Rascunho',
  1: 'Enviado',
  2: 'Processando',
  9: 'Processado',
  3: 'Agendado',
  4: 'Protocolizado',
  5: 'Suspenso',
  6: 'Erro protocolo',
  7: 'Erro processamento',
  8: 'Erro leitura'
}];

function constantFormatter(params) {
    return STATUS[0][params];
}

console.log(constantFormatter(4));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you cannot edit the original array, you can get object values from it using [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values).

```js
const STATUS = [{
  0: 'Rascunho',
  1: 'Enviado',
  2: 'Processando',
  9: 'Processado',
  3: 'Agendado',
  4: 'Protocolizado',
  5: 'Suspenso',
  6: 'Erro protocolo',
  7: 'Erro processamento',
  8: 'Erro leitura'
}];

console.log(Object.values(STATUS[0]));
```